# html - input unable to be focused on when clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

Hi great people of stackoverflow,

I have a problem with my input box where I am unable to click on it meaning that I cannot type anything into it.

[FMSSB.COM](http://fmssb.com/interactive/xavian/altwww-v2)

The input box is in the 8th slide. Use your mouse to navigate to the 8th slide.

I used 2 jquery plugins which are as shown below.
iDangero.us Mobile Touch Slider
Malibu Custom Scrollbar

I've also set the z-index to 1000 which should place it above the rest but it still does not work.

However, when you keep pressing tab repetitively, you can reach the input box and enter value in it.

I hope I got my message across.

Thanks.

P.S. Do note it looks weird on a large screen because I don't have the proper styling for bigger window screens. So far it works on a 1280px width screen.

Comment: This looks like a javascript/jquery problem, rather than a css problem.  If you can tab through your website in order to reach it, that has nothing to do with css, thats just styling and has nothing to do with functionality. Do you have a function linked to that page or even to that input bar?

Comment: no i dont have any function linked to the input bar

Comment: If you turn off CSS, you still can't type in the input box.  This is not a CSS problem.  Your JavaScript is touching that element and disabling it.

Comment: is this the problem where the mousedown event has a return false?

Comment: @XavianTracy You active in this question?

Comment: this question is perfectly valid. and im glad i found it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### It is because of Swiper

The `Swiper 1.3 - Mobile Touch Slider` would make everything to be untouched / unclickable. So, you need to set the property, `simulateTouch` to `false`. This will allow the Swiper to ignore mouse events.

In all your `.swipe()` functions, give this parameter.

```
simulateTouch: false
```

When you initiate Swiper, use something like this:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', { 
    speed:750, 
    mode:'vertical',
    simulateTouch: false
});
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I actually found out what was the problem and it was exactly as you said.

Comment: this doesnt work with new versions of slider. ive added an answer for new version

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to make sure about something, you mentioned that you set the `z-index: 1000;` but did you set the `position: absolute;`?? The `z-index` property will only work with the `position` attribute set to `absolute`

Comment: i set position:absolute and z-index:1000 to the div that contains the input box

Comment: try removing the <div class="left">...</div> and all its contents and see what happenes

Answer (score 0):

i solved this on new versions of slider like this. took me long to reach this

```
           $('.swiper-slide select').on('mousedown touchstart MSPointerDown', function(e){
           e.stopPropagation();
   }); 
           $('.swiper-slide input').on('mousedown touchstart MSPointerDown', function(e){
           e.stopPropagation();
   }); 
           $('.swiper-slide textarea').on('mousedown touchstart MSPointerDown', function(e){
           e.stopPropagation();
   });
```